# Using the Extension dojo layout Content Pane and Border Pane

Tags: dojo, xpages

I have created a simple Layout control using the Dojo Content Pane Border Container and Border Pane.

```
<xe:djContentPane id="djContentPane1" style="width:auto; height:500px;">
        <xe:djBorderContainer id="djBorderContainer1">
            <xe:djBorderPane id="djBorderPane1" region="top">Header
            </xe:djBorderPane>

            <xe:djBorderPane id="djBorderPane2" region="center">Main
                Body
            </xe:djBorderPane>

            <xe:djBorderPane id="djBorderPane3" region="bottom">Footer
            </xe:djBorderPane>

            <xe:djBorderPane id="djBorderPane4" region="left"
                style="width:auto">main Navigator
            </xe:djBorderPane>
         </xe:djBorderContainer>
    </xe:djContentPane>
```

It does pretty much what I want (obviously no styling on it at this point) except for two things:
1. I can't figure out how to make the djContentPane fill the full space available on the screen. The width:auto works but there does not appear to be a corresponding height specification. 
2. I added a repeat control view into the region="center" and it displays fine except when the content exceeds the height available there is no scrollbar. I think as I read some of the help this should be the default for the "center" djBorderPane. Do I have to define the scrollbar?

Comment: Have you tried using css stylings for both tasks? Can't try it right now, but I'm sure the content pane is somehow rendered as a div so that you can apply both width: and height: for it. As for the scrollbar: I'd try to wrap the repeat inside a div, then set scrollbar: options through css

Comment: It looks like you try to design your own layout control since the XPages layout control didn't quite work as you expected. That's a bit of a slippery road. The dojo controls are less likely to be easy skinnable (the layout control already has OneUI and Bootstrap as targets). You might end up spending a lot of time and not getting the result you are looking for. Why not share in a new questions your design goals, so the community can chip in to make it easier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ad 1.: use `height:100%` instead of "auto"; works fine for me, at least using Firefox (haven't tried other browsers)

ad 2.: I put a panel around the repeat as recommended in my above comment. Then I added overflow:auto; as a style property to the panel. Instead of using an extra panel you also could add that to the repeat itself, but I usually prefer styling an outer div because sometimes you want to set the removeRepeat property and then lose its own styling possibilities. Here's my portion of the border panel's code:

```
<xe:djBorderPane id="djBorderPane2" region="center">Main Body
    <xp:panel id="outerDiv" style="width:100%;height:100%;overflow:auto;">
        <xp:repeat id="repeat1" rows="30" var="rowData">
            <xp:this.value>
                <![CDATA[#{javascript:["row1", "row2", "row3", "row4"]}]]>
            </xp:this.value>
            <xp:panel id="innerDiv">
                <xp:text escape="true" id="computedField1" value="#{javascript:rowData}">
                </xp:text>
            </xp:panel>
        </xp:repeat>
    </xp:panel>
</xe:djBorderPane>
```

again, works fine for me

Comment: Strange behaviour. I added the width:100%;height:95%;overflow:auto; to the repeat control - made the height95% because it sometimes would display a part line. But that is not the issue. When the repeat first displays the scrollBar appears on the page as it should, if I click the page 2 of the pager it changes to page 2 but removes the scrollBar - even though it should be there - and the scrollBar does not appear when I go back to page 1, but does if I do a browser refresh. When I navigate to page 2 or ?? there appears to be a change in the style the background changes from white to grey.

Comment: Looking at the css properties in FireBug the css class layoutMainDoc where I define the properties width, height and overflow shows on the div. I have applied the properties explicitely to the repeat as well as using the css class. Likewise put it in a panel wrapping the repeat always with the same result. Probaly missing something pretty simple but ???

Comment: This is to complicated to just make a guess. Maybe you should start over with a fresh question, then showing the whole picture; f.e. there was no mentioning of a pager in your post before, nor what id the pager is refreshing, or where the pager is located etc. Just like @stwissel recommended in his comment above